# Can I use Nth-child to skip the first item then select 2 skip 2?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would need an nht-child rules that would match this:
◻ ◼ ◼ ◻ ◻ ◼ ◼ ◻ ◻ ◼ ◼ ◻

I tried several combinaisons on [CSS-Tricks Nth-child-tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/), but nothing worked.
Is that even possible?

Comment: He wants to target 1 **2 3** 4 5 **6 7** 8 (ie. 2,3,6,7)

Comment: Your title is confusing because it doesn't match the pattern. Do you want to select 2, then skip 2? Or do you want to "skip 1, then indefinitely: select 2, skip 2"?

Comment: @Harry http://grab.by/AtO4

Comment: @JohnFeminella my bad. I want to skip the first one than selected 2 and skip 2. (Edit I updated my title according to your comment. thx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of any single-rule way to do it, but you can always just target two separate patterns with the same rule:

```
:nth-child(4n+2),
:nth-child(4n+3) {
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: +1 I don't know why I didn't think about combining 2 separate patterns. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This one gave me a headache, but I figured out how to do it in a single rule!!

You'd have to use the `:not()` selector, since it can be placed sequentially, so `element:not(:nth-child(4n + 1)):not(:nth-child(4n + 4))` would do the trick.

In other words, it is selecting all, except the **1st** and **4th** on each *4n* range...

```css
li:not(:nth-child(4n + 1)):not(:nth-child(4n + 4)) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To me, the accepted answer is the more readable one (and the one I'd use if working on a team). But I'm giving you +1 because I appreciate the cleverness and dedication to seeing if it was possible. :)

Comment: You're awesome, I couldn't figure this out.  I modified it to go 2 by 2 via  ELEMENT > div:not(:nth-child(4n + 1)):not(:nth-child(4n + 2))  Because I made a whole thing that could use striping but didn't contain each element pairing to just do an (even) selector